# Scala. Присвоить в if

Tags: if, сравнение, scala, оператор-присваивания

Имеется кусочек кода (для примера)

```
var i = 0
if( (i = 1) == 1)
    println(1)
```

В if получится false, так как присвоение произойдет после сравнения. Как сделать аналогично данному примеру, чтобы в if было true.

Comment: а зачем так делать?

Comment: ну здесь я привел такой кусочек для примера и смысл он не имеет. просто, если использовать в циклах типа while, где необходимо считывать и присваивать, не городить лишних костылей. 
Например
`var len = 0
while({
    len = stream.read(...)
    len == -1
})
    doSomeThing
`

Comment: Обычно лучше использовать `val`-ы и immutable коллекции.
Но если уж нужна какая-то оптимизация с `var` и `while`, есть смысл писать максимально очевидный код

Answer (score 2):

Здравствуйте, в scala каждое выражение возвращает некоторое значение.
В вашем примере выражение (i = 1) возвращает тип Unit. Т.е. вы пишите:

```
    var i = 0
    val unit1: Unit = i = 1
    if (unit1 == 1)
      println(1)
```

Опишите подробно случаи которые у вас вызывают проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Все, разобрался.

```
var i = 0
if({
    i = 1
    i == 1})
    println(1)
```